# How to center a background image vertically within header

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

CSS

```
#container  {
width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #000000;
}

#header {
width: 884px;
height: 300px;
position: relative;
margin: auto;
background-image: url(babygoatbooksbanner.png); text-align:center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="headertoo"></div>
<div id="leftnav"> dude wheres my car</div>
<div id="body"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: First of all, it seems your HTML didn't get posted. Secondly, I don't see where you attempted vertical centering...try adding `background-position:center`; maybe that's what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the `background-image`?

Try this:

```
background: url(babygoatbooksbanner.png) scroll no-repeat center transparent;
```

Comment: I tried this and it made the image disappear for some reason.